# onDataChange is not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an Android App and I'm using Firebase. I can't understand why the onDataChange function is not called.

I also add a log in the onCancelled so I understood that also the onCancelled function is not called. The reference of the database is right.

```
public void fillHashMap() {

    lela_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    lela_database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            HashMap languages_in = new HashMap();

            for (DataSnapshot lan : dataSnapshot.child("languages").getChildren()) {
                languages_in.put(lan.getKey(), lan.getValue());
            }

            languages = languages_in;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onCancelled called ");
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please show us your database structure

Comment: languages
     language1
     language2

Comment: I'm sorry but this `- languages + language1 + language2` cannot be your database structure. Please add a `json` file or an image.

Comment: I was trying to setup a list. The structure is the one written by iamareebjamal in the answer below

Comment: That's not a database structure. Please try to dwonload the `json` file from your Firebase console. In the right corner you'll see 3 dots. Click on them an than click on `Export JSON`.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you pass the name of your database in the `getReference()` function ?

Also you may try `reference.addChildEventListener(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that `onDataChange` is not called, you haven't put a log in there.

Secondly, your database structure seems to be this :

- languages

  - item 1
  - item 1
    ...

If so, you can directly write

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("languages")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                      @Override
                      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Use the children to map to HashMap

                      }
}
```

Comment: I putted a Log in it. I deleted it before posting the code. 
Now I tried this code and it does not work

Comment: Did you initialize the Firebase Instance correctly using google-services.json?